# Transformer energy snubber

Tags: diodes, transformer, snubber

I own an older PC speaker set with a 10 V AC power supply.
The power-cube transformer not only has a sine with flatted tops, but also, when I turn off the speaker set, my sleeping PC wakes up. I guess the energy from the transformer is not controlled in any way.

I now plan to replace the device with a better transformer, some netfilters, and an apparatus to destroy the energy when turned off. As I haven't done a circuit like that for quite a while, I hope for some good advice.

I guess a proper solution would be two Z-diodes:

[image: example circuit]

Questions:

- Is the circuit with the two diodes a good solution?
- Would you recommend adding an additional serial resistor to limit the current through the diodes?
- Would you apply the diode circuit on the secondary side as shown or on the primary side?
- TVS or Zener diodes?

Thx in advance.

Comment: The usual solution is a varistor (MOV) across the primary.  An iec socket and input filter is another simple and common solution. Varistors and input filters can be harvested from older equipment, for example a treadmill if you don’t have easy means if purchasing such components.

Comment: Your transformer model needs much more magnetising inductance ,needs K close to unity ,Needs some parasitic capacitance .Sort out the model and see ringing ,then supress the ringing with a RC snubber

Answer (score 1):

Similar thing happens to me when I turn my kitchen extractor fan off: Sleeping PC wakes up or the mouse of the turned-off PC turns on by itself.

Since the load of the line is an inductive load (transformer, motor, ballast inductor, relay coil, etc) a spike can occur at a sudden turn-off event. This spike is then coupled to the PC (interestingly not snubbed by the PC PSU input circuitry) and somehow converted/de-modulated into a signal for the mainboard.

It could be better if you could catch the input sine's zero crossing during turn off to decrease the spike's amplitude but a more practical and easy-to-apply solution is to tame this inevitable spike **at the supply input side** by placing a properly-sized MOV across the line and neutral.

Comment: I have several surge protection Devices installed, so I guess the enegy is passed via the line-in. Even there I have placed an audio transformer. But still the energy needs to go somewhere. "It could be better if you could catch the input sine's zero crossing during turn off" - I do not want to have a more complicated circut in the power supply than in the device itself :-) Also I prefer passive components there. It should be cheep and reliable